# Can't remove my saved places in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a bunch of saved places like this one that I can't remove them:

[image]

After I click on it, doesn't appear as saved (`Save` button doesn't have the green flag on it)

[image]

I've tried going to `Menu` -> `Your places` -> `Saved` -> Click on any of the categories (`Want to go` in my case) and it appears in the list:

[image]

but if I click on the element, is the same as if I click on the map's location.

[image]

Unrelated with this site, but I've tried also to remove in the android app and as soon as I click on the green flag, it appears "Can't establish the connection". Worth to mention, this is not a network issue as I can click another locations without the mentioned message.

[image]

I found [a solution](https://support.google.com/maps/forum/AAAAQuUrST87acAeyBpT9c/?hl=en&gpf=d/topic/maps/7acAeyBpT9c#promoted) to enter [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/), but it only appear `Starred places`, not `Favorites` or `Want to go`.
Also worth to mention this happens only with some places, not with all of them. No idea what I'm doing different with one or another.

Comment: Both of the links are dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found how to remove them, going to `Menu` -> `Your places` -> `Saved` -> Click on the`⋮` icon of the category desired -> `Edit list`.
Then here you could remove the location clicking on the `X` button:

[image]

Isn't the most friendly way, but is the only one I could find.

Comment: I have phantom places that will re-appear no matter how many times I click the cross.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff I have the same experience using a desktop computer (Mac, OS 12.6.5, Chrome 112.0.5615) and following the procedure outlined in the answer. This was unaffected by clearing the files and images cache.